# Google Plus Circle Counter based on {userId} on PHP

Tags: php, google-plus

Can any one please suggest How do i find Google Plus Circle count based on UserId.
Let me give some brief example.

I want to create a php based systems where user can put their googleplus UserID. then show No of People Him/Her circle.

Like an Example.

UserID - **106189723444098348646**

Output - **2395969** have him in circles

Also is it possible to use http://www.circlecount.com API if have. or else using this

http://www.circlecount.com/button_followercount.js.php?id=106189723444098348646&lang=en

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the official APIs. You can see the list of available methods in the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/).

Comment: Hi , Jenny Thanks for the information. But it inquisitive to know , How "circlecout.com" fetch User Circle Count along with Following Count. Any Idea . Thanks.

Comment: I haven't seen their code, but it's likely they are scraping Google+ web pages, which is against the terms of service (and really brittle).